# while loop with variables? 1234

Tags: php, loops, variables

I tried to create a while loop.

```
<div>
    <?php
        while($i < 100){
            echo $i + 100
            $i++;

            if($i = 23){
                echo 'reached!';
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

But I just get errors. What did i make wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: When posting a question asking about errors its always a good idea to include the errors in the post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: There's a difference between = and ==. And you're using the wrong one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not hard to fix.

You can get the mistake from the errors.

1. you forgot a ";" after the `echo $i + 100`
2. `if ($i = 23)` have to be `if($i == 23)`

So finaly it looks like:

```
<?php
     while($i < 100){
         echo $i + 100;
         $i++;

         if($i == 23){
             echo 'reached!';
         }
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: glad to help. You can set the mark if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `;` after `echo $i + 100` :

```
echo $i + 100;
```